Should nomeclature and terminology tags be synonimized?
I have 2 questions based on what the official term is for a mini/micro/tiny/nano-figure.
One is tagged terminology, the other nomeclature.  I see many more entries under terminology; should nomeclature be a synonym of terminology? 

Sounds like a reasonable suggestion, nomenclature is a harder word to spell and type ;-) 

I've setup synonyms for both nomeclature and nomenclature which should help going forward

Consider that the tag is currently "nomeclature" without the second 'n'.

Indeed, I didn't realise it was misspelt when I initially posted that.

I've replaced it; there was only one instance other than my own question.
